# Proving logarithmic maths graphically

Tags: logarithms

I'm just going through some further maths units as I prepare for a PHD in chemical engineering. I'm finding the thought processes to be invaluable in my problem solving skills.

However, I recently came unstuck on this question....and while I know I can't be helped here due to the requirement to construct a graph, I wondered what would be the right way a mathematician would approach this?
Show graphically that the following figures support the belief that a relationship of the form =^ exists and use your graph to find approximate values for the constants  and .

5    8   12   14     20    30 
 22.4 45.3 83.1 104.8 178.9 328.6

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship $y=ax^k$ holds, then taking logs of both sides yields
$$
\log y = \log a + k\log x.
$$
This means that plotting $\log y$ against $\log x$ should give a straight line with slope $k$ and intercept $\log a$.

Comment: Thank you for this help. So all I need to do is plot a graph with log y and another with log a + k log x. Will the slope be the linkage? I will use desmos.

Comment: Make a new data set with $\log x$ as the independent variable and $\log y$ as the dependent variable. Plot these pairs of variables -- $\log x$ on the horizontal axis, and $\log y$ on the vertical axis (instead of the original $x$ and $y$). These pairs should exhibit a straight line relationship, whereas the original pairs will not. The slope of the line will be $k$ and the intercept will be $\log a$.

Comment: What would be the quickest way to compute log x and log y as values? My methodology is lacking.

So logy is not being changed. Logx is the independent variable and so changes in terms of value as it is the variable being measured.

Comment: So for example, for the first value, I would just take the log of 5?

Which would be 0.699

Comment: I have achieved this now!

Comment: Thanks for your assistance grand_chat!

Comment: Great. I assume you used a calculator to compute log x and log y? (I don't get 0.699 as log of 5.)